# How to get Testcase status in QC From Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, hp-quality-center

I want to fetch QC execution result from EXCEL.
I want to create an excel where i will write few testcases name and will click some execute button and it should fetch those textcases result and related field in excel from QC.So please help me to do that.I am not expecting the full code but if i get few steps or excel-Qc connection basic ideas that will help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help you get started...

```
Set QCConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
Dim sUserName, sPassword
sUserName = "user name" '-- change me
sPassword = "" '-- change me
QCConnection.InitConnectionEx "ALM bin link" '-- change me
QCConnection.Login sUserName, sPassword
```